# Strange behavior with function strncpy?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging

In my project,I have met these strange problem with `strncpy`. I have checked the [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/). But the function `strncpy` behavior make me confused. 
In this [function](https://github.com/einverne/BigSeg/blob/master/BigDictSeg.cpp#L356), when it runs to `strncpy(subs,target,term_len);`

[image: status of variables]

While I don't know why there is two blanks after the string?!!! It is a big project, I cannot paste all the code here. Following is just a piece. All my code is [here](https://github.com/einverne/BigSeg/blob/master/BigDictSeg.cpp).

```
char* subs = new char[len];
while(top<=bottom){
    char* term = m_strTermTable[bottom].strterm;
    int term_len = strlen(term);
    memset(subs,'\0',len);
    strncpy(subs,target,term_len);
    int subs_len = strlen(subs);
    int re = strcmp(subs,term);
    if (re == 0)
    {
        return term_len;
    }
    bottom--;
}
delete[] subs;
```

Comment: If this is c++ why aren't you just using `std::string`s?

Comment: strncpy does **not** always add a null terminator. It's a particularly stupid function which I would avoid using.

Comment: Have you checked `term_len` value? may it be that `term_len` is bigger than `len`?

Comment: @jcm I have checked that `term_len` is equal to `len`.

Comment: Instead of `char* subs = new char[len];` you could use `std::vector<char> subs(len);` to avoid the memory leak in case the `return` is reached.

Comment: The return type of `strlen` is `size_t`, so `term_len` should be a `size_t`.

Comment: @einverne If it is equals then, you're overwriting last `\0`, `len` should be `term_len+1`

Comment: @jcm Thanks a lot. With the help of Frerich Raabe I solve the problem.. Thank you all.

Comment: **Every** use of `strncpy` that I've seen on SO has been pointless. The uses typically just replace a buffer overrun with data corruption, as this one does. There are **very few** situations where `strncpy` is appropriate; there's no good reason for inexperienced programmers to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`strncpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/) does not add a terminating null byte if the source string is longer than the maximum number of characters (i.e. in your case, that would be if `strlen(target) > term_len` holds). If that happens, `subs` may or may not be null terminated correctly.

Try changing your `strncpy` call to

```
strncpy(subs, target, term_len-1);
```

so that even if `strncpy` doesn't add a terminating null byte, `subs` will still be null-terminated correctly due to the previous `memset` call.

Now, that being said - you could avoid using a separate `subs` buffer altogether (which leaks anyway in case the control flow gets to the `return` statement) by just using [`strncmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/) as in

```
while(top<=bottom) {
    char* term = m_strTermTable[bottom].strterm;
    int term_len = strlen(term);
    if (strncmp(term, target, term_len) == 0) {
        return term_len;
    }
    bottom--;
}
```